# How to check if specific time has passed

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am start my operation and one of the argument my command line application get is `Number` that represent how much time my operation need to run.

```
int duration = int.Parse(args[0]) // run my operation for this time in minutes
```

This is what i have try (not working):

```
...
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
// check whether this time in minutes passed
if (start.Minute > duration )
    break;
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `DateTime`.

Comment: What is `duration` exactly? And what do you mean by _not working_?

Comment: You may want to do something with `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(duration)`.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` tells you what time it is *now*, it has no knowledge of durations.  Maybe you want to use a `Timer`?

Comment: duration is the time in minutes i want my operation to run

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: use UtcNow

```
    void DoWork(int durationInMinutes)
    {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TimeSpan breakDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(durationInMinutes);

        // option 1
        while (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime < breakDuration)
        {
            // do some work
        }

        // option 2
        while (true)
        {
            // do some work
            if (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime > breakDuration)
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think that option 2 the work should come after the if...otherwise the two code snippets dont do exactly the same thing

Comment: This answer would be a bit better if it used DateTime.UtcNow instead of DateTime.Now for startTime and in the while loop.

Comment: @Rick Davin - I'm all for using UTC when applicable, but what does it help here? in my opinion it just makes debugging slightly harder in this case.

Comment: @ShayD if the app is running across a DST transition, then for a given instant DateTime.Now could occur before startTime, and therefore break the intended logic.  I know that NodaTime advocates Jon Skeet and Matt Johnson both encourage use of DateTime.UtcNow when working with moments in time (such as your answer) as a matter of standard practice.

Comment: More on why UtcNow is preferred: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2012/01/10/datetime-utcnow-is-generally-preferable-to-datetime-now.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

For this  you can use `StopWatch`  by defining

```
StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
watch.Start();
```

and where ever ur code finishes running write

```
watch.Stop();
```

By using stopwach you can see you are running time of your application in detail. Of course if I am correct to understand you.